# moveByOffset().contextClick() clicks outside the WebElement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Selenium WebDriver and Programming. I am trying to right click on the link (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/2.48.2 link under Selenium Standalone Server)but code below right-clicks on the outside of the link and hence the contextual menu is not relevant. How can I make the right-click on the link above? I took the right xpath but still....

```
    WebElement dom = obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[3]/a"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Actions act = new Actions(obj);
    int x = dom.getLocation().getX();
    int y = dom.getLocation().getY();
    act.moveByOffset(x,y).contextClick().build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    act.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    act.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    obj.quit();
```

Comment: its looks question is confusing to me..can you help me with  what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi Murali, I am trying to right click on the link (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/2.48.2 link under Selenium Standalone Server)but code I wrote right-clicks on the outside of the link and hence the contextual menu is not relevant. How can I make the right-click on the link? I took the right xpath but still....

Comment: posted answer..please check

Answer (score 0):

If you want to right click on download link (xpath=.//*[@id='mainContent']/p[3]/a) then

```
 Actions rightClick=new Actions(driver);
rightClick.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainContent']/p[3]/a"))).build().perform();
```

Let me know how it works..

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Thank you very much Murali!! This worked. Problem was with moveByOffset only.